# convert date function of sql server into oracle date function

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I convert the following sql server code in oracle

```
DATEADD(MINUTE,column1,column2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert col1 value to minute then add into date column

```
Select columk,columk + (intervalColumn*60)/(24*60*60) from t
```

See Sample [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c93ce/1)

Answer (score 0):

To translate this you'd do something along the lines of

```
COLUMN2 + (COLUMN1 / (60 * 24))
```

So if you have a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (COLUMN1  NUMBER,
                  COLUMN2  DATE);
```

and populated with data:

```
INSERT INTO TBL (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
  VALUES (12, TO_DATE('08-JUN-2015 13:24:56', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

then executing

```
SELECT COLUMN1,
       COLUMN2,
       COLUMN2 + (COLUMN1 / (60 * 24)) AS ADDED_DATES
  FROM TBL;
```

will give you the result `June, 08 2015 13:36:56` for the ADDED_DATES column.

The reason this works is that in Oracle adding 1 to a DATE value is equivalent to adding one day. Thus, to add a number of minutes you have to add a fraction that is the number of minutes divided by the number of minutes in a day, or 60 * 24. In our example above we're adding (12 / (60 * 24)), or (12 / 1440), which simplifies to (1 / 120).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d08e/1)